# Dropdown Menus fail on mouse click with 'Wrong type argument'

Tags: osx, menu-bar, emacs24.4

Emacs 24.4 installed on OS X via homebrew: `brew install --with-gnutls --cocoa`

Dropdown menus work fine with `<F10>`:

[image: Dropdown menus work fine with <code><F10></code>]

But fail when clicked on with the mouse:

[image]

I have recompiled as many files as I can, and the problem persists. Some clues, if not an outright solution, would be great. Is something else eating the mouse clicks? Might Helm be interfering?

My base Emacs configuration is prelude, but I am about to remove all my configuration and revert to a vanilla setup to see if I can make the dropdowns work.

Comment: Try to replicate the behavior with `emacs -Q` (which inhibits loading of the init file).  If the behavior is still present then you probably ran into a bug and should file a bug report with `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Is it really unexpected behavior? On my system (24.3 on linux), with `emacs -Q -nw`, the menubar does not react to the mouse at all (well, it can select text as any other line of the terminal... but that's not really useful). Or is it some specific feature of the OSX build?

Comment: @T.Verron: Yes. On MS Windows, from `emacs -Q -nw`, the mouse (either `mouse-1` or `mouse-2` works fine with the menus. Sounds like a bug with the OP's build/platform.

Comment: @T.Verron - this is a new feature in 24.4: From the NEWS - `** Support for menus on text-mode terminals. If the terminal supports a mouse, clicking on the menu bar, or on sensitive portions of the mode line or header line, will drop down the menu defined at that position. Likewise, clicking C-mouse-1, C-mouse-2, or C-mouse-3 on the text area will pop up the menus defined for those locations.`

Comment: `emacs -Q` or `emacs -Q -nw` results in nothing happening onClick, since the mouse is not enabled by default (so it seems). Simply loading an init.el containing the mouse enabler means that menus open in a new buffer, well, sort of, they don't seem to be the right menus.

Comment: @v-v Ah, sorry, I missed that item indeed. No wonder it wouldn't work on 24.3. Now, I don't find any mention of any "mouse enabler" anywhere, and @Drew reported that it works with `-Q` on windows. On my linux box (freshly upgraded), my menus are as nonresponsive as before, so I take it that my terminal doesn't "support a mouse". What's interesting is that yours shows that it recieves some event with either prelude or your init.el, but not with `-Q`. Can you isolate the minimal code that enables that?

Comment: @T.Verron - I've switched to a bare `init.el` file containing only `;; Enable mouse support
(unless window-system
  (require 'mouse)
  (xterm-mouse-mode t)
  (global-set-key [mouse-4] '(lambda ()
                              (interactive)
                              (scroll-down 1)))
  (global-set-key [mouse-5] '(lambda ()
                              (interactive)
                              (scroll-up 1)))
  (defun track-mouse (e))
  (setq mouse-sel-mode t)
)
` and it seems that random menus open up in a new buffer. Clicking on the File menu gives me this: http://bit.ly/1wkUGqk

Comment: Going to recompile from scratch without any options, let's see if I can trace a bug or narrow it down. Thanks everyone for all comments so far.

Comment: @T.Verron: Sorry, I was checking in Emacs 24.4 (and it works there, on Windows). I somehow thought that is what you are using.

Comment: @Drew That's what I am using now. At first I thought the question was about a regression in 24.4, that's why I wouldn't understand. @v-v Just tested on my system, `(xterm-mouse-mode t)` is what enabled the magic for me... Well, it works, but with an old-style buffer, sort of what you described. So I guess you have two problems: the old menu instead of the new one, which appears on a vanilla setup; and the error with your full configuration, which seems to originate in your configuration.

Comment: @T.Verron: BTW, I think that if you use two at-sign designations in the same comment (e.g., me and v-v), it is only the first target that gets a notification. So if you want someone to be notified, use a separate comment.

Comment: @T.Verron & @Drew It looks like the mouse is calling `tmm-menubar` rather than `menu-bar-open` - starting from a vanilla install until I can reproduce the argument error!

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in one question.

First, the error message on mouse event in your screenshots is likely to be caused by your configuration, you should try to isolate it by dichotomy (comment out half of your init file, see if the problem still appears, etc.)

Then the fact that `emacs -Q` does not provide mouse support. That seems to imply that mouse support needs to be enabled somehow. Several functions for this purpose seem to exist ([manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text_002dOnly-Mouse.html#Text_002dOnly-Mouse)):

- `xterm-mouse-mode`: enables very basic mouse functionality ("only non-modified single-mouse clicks"); as you noticed, it also uses the old menus with `tmm`, rather than the new one that appears with `<f10>`.
- `t-mouse-support`, alias for `gpm-mouse-support`: if your system has [gpm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPM_(software)) running, and if your emacs was compiled with gpm, enable mouse support in the terminal. This is reportedly only for GNU/Linux, [it appears to be available for mac if you use X11](https://serverfault.com/questions/104494/the-way-to-use-mouse-over-ssh-on-mac-osx) (I have no idea how hard to achieve it is).

None of this provides multi-platform, out-of-the-box mouse support. On the other hand, Drew reported that on w32, it works with `emacs -Q`. Mouse support indeed seems to be [handled differently](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/MS_002dDOS-Mouse.html#MS_002dDOS-Mouse) in w32 consoles.

Given that the manual doesn't seem to mention anything more, I will go with a guess: the "if your terminal supports a mouse" in the news corresponds to having one of the mouse modes enabled (either dos mouse, xterm mouse or gpm mouse). Then the news is not about supporting the mouse out of the box, but rather about having it work for the menus *as well*.

Why not use a graphical frame? `:)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply - of ten suggestions in one answer :)

Comment: I finally gave up on this last night, but here are my findings: The error message did indeed go away after disabling most of the configuration. I switched around the various mouse modes, and only `xterm-mouse-mode` is useful in iTerm/Terminal on OS X. You are correct in that. X11 on the Mac is 'XQuartz'. My final discovery was that mouse clicks seem to trigger `tmm-menubar`, when they should be triggering `menu-bar-open`. I don't know how to fix this, and even after that, I cannot make emacs recognize a mouse click on a menu item. Boo :(

Comment: Oh, and yes, of course, there is always the GUI version, but I have a very particular tmux-based setup in my terminal involving more than just my editor (Yes, I know, emacs can probably do it too) so I am some way off switching to the GUI. I will surely continue to periodically investigate The Mystery Of The Mouse Menu, but there are far better things to be doing right now :D